# Cant run .exe on other machine without DLLs even though I use Costura.Fody

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

So I made my first C#.NET - Application in Visual Studio. To run the application without all the DLLs in the same Directory I used Costura.Fody which works fine. But when I want to run the .EXE on another machine it doesn't work because it cant find the DLLs.

I don't know if I made a mistake or its just don't work like this. I also would be happy if I just could put the DLLs in a folder next to the executable file.

That's my \bin\debug Folder
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you give a screenshot of your bin/debug folder after a clean/rebuild?

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? What happens **exactly**?

Comment: why not use the ilmerge ? https://ilmergegui.codeplex.com

Comment: @mjwills the application crashes because it looks for some DLL's in the path of my machine, which are not available on another machine. But I thought the Costura.Fody - package put all DLL's into the .exe file. The size of the .exe increases too.

Comment: @jαsοndιnAlt ilmerge is the next thing I want to try, but first I want to know what's wrong with what I'm doing now.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the application crashing?

Comment: First write a decent error handling in your main module (usually program.cs within .exe) - log the exception to file or show the exception details in message box & share stack trace with us.

Comment: Is there anything logged that you can see in Event Viewer?